# Variable that refers to the project directory in Qt Creator?

Tags: variables, path, project, qt-creator

I'm working on a cross-platform Qt application and the paths are different on Mac OS X and Windows. Since the project is on an external hard-drive, the drive letter also occasionally changes on Windows.

For that reason, I would like to refer to the project directory using a variable, preferably a built-in one. In particular, is there such a variable usable in:

- The .pro file?
- The build settings (in the Projects tab)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in [_PRO_FILE_PWD_](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#pro-file-pwd) variable contains the path to the directory containing the project file in use. That variable may be useful for you.

Answer (score 13):

To complete, @Bill's answer, the way to refer to the source path in the Build Settings is to use `%{sourceDir}`.

`%{buildDir}` is also available.

Answer (score 6):

Since I struggled a bit to find it, I'm adding it here.

In addition to `%{sourceDir}` and `%{buildDir}`, you could use `%{CurrentDocument:Path}`, `%{CurrentDocument:FilePath}` and `%{CurrentProject:Path}` to refer to specific files and folders in the project directory.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where the documentation for these variables are? Is it just in the drop down or anywhere in the manual?

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_ on windows, because it contains forward slash allways. You need to fix slash using shell_path.

```
 $$shell_path($$_PRO_FILE_PWD_)
```