# What are QtCreator build step variable names (such as %{buildDir})?

Tags: qt-creator

I am specifying a build step which shall run in the project directory. So if this is supposed to work in general, I need a symbol representing project directory, similar to `%{buildDir}`, which represents the build directory.

[Qt manual](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html#using-qt-creator-variables) only mentions nonexistent [image: (variables icon)]
**Variables** button. No such button appears on their screenshots or in the GUI I see.

I would appreciate full list of variables defined by QtCreator - like project path, target executable path, project `.pro` filename and so on.

Comment: So far, I have only found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24818296/607407) mentioning `%{sourceDir}` and `%{buildDir}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found [here, on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35982389/5163799).

It is true that the button you mention is not visible in build settings. Documentation is inconsistent about this. Fortunately as you can see in the answer linked above - the *Variables* button is available in options.

It is sad that a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15511) mentioning this is not being fixed as there are many other posts like yours. Beside bug report I see no other way to make missing *Variables* button appear on the build settings page in Qt Creator.

Comment: I created that bug report :)