# How to find the variables button in Qt creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm reading Qt Documentation, [Specifying Build Settings](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html) section. Under the 'Using Qt Creator Variables' I found following sentence.

> Select the  (Variables) button in a field to select from a list of variables that are available in a particular context.

But I found no Variables button in Qt Creator  3.3.0.  Just found the same question asked in a [forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/53252/qt-creator-variables).

Can anybody explain me what it is or where I can find the button?

Comment: No only you struggling with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271859/what-are-qtcreator-build-step-variable-names-such-as-builddir

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIGNAL AND SLOT 
 
Drop in form some button,
  *cpp file*.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->button1,SIGNAL(clicked),this,SLOT(someRecivedFunc));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    conn.close();
}

void MainWindow::someRecivedFunc(){

}
```

*h file*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include  "QMainWindow" </pre>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void someRecivedFunc();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think you misunderstood the question. I asked about a button mentioned in the Qt Documentation. It says there is a button in Qt Creator to view all available variables  in a particular context. But I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think some fields can have a select variable button, and some don't.  For example, in "Left Panel -> Projects -> Run Settings" both *Run: argument* field and *Run:working directory* field can use the select variable buttons to the right side of the fields.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I cannot found anything in the places you mentioned here. I'm using Qt creator 3.6.1 now.

Comment: Interesting.  I am use old version Qt Creator 3.4.2, which has the feature (partly, not all fields can have variable buttons).