# QT Deployment Issue

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qt-creator

So, I am admittedly pretty new to Qt and am having a lot of trouble deploying, even reading the official documentation and similar questions on here. I will explain my situation. I downloaded Qt and I think I added some extra files because I didn't know what I was doing when I was installing it. Thus, this is what my Qt directory now looks like:
[image: QT Directory]

[image: 5.14.1 Subdirectory]

As you can see, I have multiple MSVC and MinGW folders with bin subdirectories with windeployqt.exe files. I have tried to run all of them as Admin, but they instantly close after opening, and I have no idea why. On my profile within QtCreator, it says Desktop Qt 5.14.1 MinGW 64 bit or 32 bit, if that helps any. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried running them in a command line window? They aren't graphical applications. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Please specify what did you try to run? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders you're talking about are localizations with kits of libraries and tools for target compilers. When you choose some target kit for your project, Qt Creator will automatically choose tools from proper directory for you. Your goal is probably to add "Custom Process Step" to your build settings. You should go to "Projects", choose right toolkit and add "Custom Process Step" to "Build Steps":

[image]

**Command** is path to windeployqt.exe application localized in your toolkit bin directory.

**Arguments** are run options, you can read about them here ([link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html))

**Working directory** is location to execute this step. By default is variable with project build directory. More about variables here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970727/use-of-variables-like-builddir-in-qtcreator-kit-settings-in-qt5/35982389))

When step created like that is enabled, after compilation of your project application will be automatically deployed to build directory.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I figured out the windeployqt.exe but now I am getting error 0x000007b after having an error “missing libgcc_seh_s-1.dll” which I dragged from my minGW. Any feedback on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know much about building with minGW, but maybe this will be helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635/mingw-exe-requires-a-few-gcc-dlls-regardless-of-the-code)